# is it possible to redirect old urls to new SEO friendly urls using client side router?

Tags: url, next.js

In my next.js app, I have an object called 'loremipsum'. Loremipsum had an alphanumeric id alongside its name.

Originally, I had the website's urls take the form abc.com/loremipsum/id. I've changed it now to abc.com/loremipsum/name.

I used the next.js client side dynamic router, and I have a file [loremipsumName].tsx for the url.

But the old links are still used by others, is it possible to redirect it to the new links?

How do i redirect my old links (abc.com/id) to the new links (abc.com/name)?